# Model group and order

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have Order model, which belogns to User model by field user_id.
Now I want to get 1 OLDEST order per each user. For example:

```
id = 0, user_id = 1, created = 2012-10-10 20:36:42
id = 1, user_id = 1, created = 2012-10-10 19:36:42
id = 2, user_id = 1, created = 2012-10-10 21:36:42

id = 3, user_id = 2, created = 2012-10-10 22:36:42
id = 4, user_id = 2, created = 2012-10-10 21:36:42
id = 5, user_id = 2, created = 2012-10-10 23:36:42
```

So result should be:

```
id = 1, user_id = 1, created = 2012-10-10 19:36:42
id = 4, user_id = 2, created = 2012-10-10 21:36:42
```

I am using following find options for now:

```
array(
    'group' => 'user_id',
    'order' => array('MIN(created) DESC'),
)
```

and also tried with `'order' => array('created DESC')`

but it doesn't work - it seems that GROUPING orders is done always before ORDERING.
How I can force the find method to order records by created field before grouping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `HAVING` clause to filter the group. To construct the query with CakePHP, you'll need to include the clause in the `ORDER` clause.

```
$this->Order->find('all', array(
  'group' => 'user_id HAVING created = MIN(created)',
  'order' => array('created DESC')
));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use CakePHP's [Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html):

```
//User model
public $actsAs = array('Containable');

public function oldestOrderPerUser() {
    $this->recursive = -1;

    $this->find('all', array(
        'contain' => array(
            'Order' => array(
                'order' => array('created asc'),
                'limit' => 1
            )
        )
    ));
}
```

This finds all users (feel free to add 'conditions' to limit it to specific user(s), and gets the first/oldest order for each user.

Your returned data will look something like this:

```
0 => array(
    'User' => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'John Doe',
        'email' => 'johndoe@awesome.com',
        'Order' => array(
            0 => array(
                'id' => '4',
                'user_id' => 1,
                'created' => '2012-10-10 19:36:42'
            )
        )
    )
1 => array(
    'User' => array(
        ...
```

You can limit what fields are returned in each User and Order, set conditions on either/both, limit either/both...etc etc.

I recommend putting `$this->recursive=-1;` in the AppModel to set it as the default - if you do that, you don't have to specify it before each query or in each model...etc.  And using anything other than -1 is bad practice anyway, so... works well.

I also set `public $actsAs = array('Containable');` in my AppModel.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it now, but try this way :

```
$this->Order->find('all', array(
  'fields' => array('MIN(Order.Created) as min_created'),
  'group' => 'user_id',
  'order' => array('min_created DESC')
));
```

Comment: I tried it - the min_created field is correct (the oldest date) but the Order record is wrong (with different created date)